# Kibana not starting in Windows 10

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I am using the following versions

```
Elastic Search : 8.8.0 

Kibana : 8.8.0
```

Elastic search gets started (Although it takes some time) with the following logs

```
warning: ignoring JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre-1.8; using bundled JDK
[0.064s][warning][logging] Output options for existing outputs are ignored.
[2023-06-06T18:54:34,942][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [W108GXRXP3] version[8.8.0], pid[49892], build[zip/c01029875a091076ed42cdb3a41c10b1a9a5a20f/2023-05-23T17:16:07.179039820Z], OS[Windows 10/10.0/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/20.0.1/20.0.1+9-29]
[2023-06-06T18:54:34,963][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [W108GXRXP3] JVM home [C:\Users\Desktop\elasticsearch-8.8.0\jdk], using bundled JDK [true]
[2023-06-06T18:54:34,964][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [W108GXRXP3] JVM arguments [-Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -Djava.security.manager=allow, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true, -Djava.locale.providers=SPI,COMPAT, --add-opens=java.base/java.io=org.elasticsearch.preallocate, -XX:+UseG1GC, -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\HARSH_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\elasticsearch, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,level,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -XX:+UseG1GC, -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\HARSH_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\elasticsearch, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,level,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -Xms16072m, -Xmx16072m, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=8426356736, -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30, -XX:G1ReservePercent=25, -Des.distribution.type=zip, --module-path=C:\Users\Harsh_Mistry\OneDrive - Dell Technologies\Desktop\elasticsearch-8.8.0\lib, --add-modules=jdk.net, --add-modules=org.elasticsearch.preallocate, -Djdk.module.main=org.elasticsearch.server]
[2023-06-06T18:54:51,804][WARN ][stderr                   ] [W108GXRXP3] SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
[2023-06-06T18:54:51,805][WARN ][stderr                   ] [W108GXRXP3] SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
[2023-06-06T18:54:51,805][WARN ][stderr                   ] [W108GXRXP3] SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
[2023-06-06T18:54:51,807][WARN ][stderr                   ] [W108GXRXP3] SLF4J: Class path contains SLF4J bindings targeting slf4j-api versions 1.7.x or earlier.
[2023-06-06T18:54:51,808][WARN ][stderr                   ] [W108GXRXP3] SLF4J: Ignoring binding found at [jar:file:///C:/Users/Harsh_Mistry/OneDrive%20-%20Dell%20Technologies/Desktop/elasticsearch-8.8.0/modules/repository-azure/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.19.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
[2023-06-06T18:54:51,808][WARN ][stderr                   ] [W108GXRXP3] SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#ignoredBindings for an explanation.
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,106][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [repository-url]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,107][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [dlm]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,110][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [x-pack-core]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,111][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [x-pack-redact]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,112][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [ingest-user-agent]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,113][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [x-pack-async-search]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,114][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [x-pack-monitoring]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,115][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [repository-s3]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,116][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [x-pack-analytics]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,117][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [x-pack-ent-search]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,118][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [x-pack-autoscaling]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,118][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,124][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [x-pack-ml]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,126][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,127][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [legacy-geo]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,127][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [x-pack-ql]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,128][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [rank-rrf]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,129][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [analysis-common]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,130][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,131][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [aggregations]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,137][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,138][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [frozen-indices]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,140][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [x-pack-identity-provider]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,141][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [x-pack-shutdown]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,142][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [x-pack-text-structure]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,143][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [snapshot-repo-test-kit]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,143][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [ml-package-loader]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,144][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [kibana]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,151][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [constant-keyword]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,153][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [x-pack-logstash]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,155][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [x-pack-ccr]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,156][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [x-pack-graph]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,156][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [parent-join]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,160][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [x-pack-enrich]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,162][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [repositories-metering-api]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,163][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [transform]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,163][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [repository-azure]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,165][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [repository-gcs]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,166][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [spatial]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,167][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [apm]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,168][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [mapper-extras]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,174][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [mapper-version]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,175][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [x-pack-aggregate-metric]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,176][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [x-pack-rollup]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,179][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [percolator]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,185][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [data-streams]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,200][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [x-pack-stack]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,208][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [rank-eval]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,213][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [reindex]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,216][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [x-pack-security]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,221][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [blob-cache]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,225][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [searchable-snapshots]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,226][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [snapshot-based-recoveries]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,228][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [x-pack-watcher]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,230][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [old-lucene-versions]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,232][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [x-pack-ilm]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,235][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [x-pack-voting-only-node]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,241][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [x-pack-deprecation]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,243][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [x-pack-fleet]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,245][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [x-pack-profiling]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,249][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [ingest-geoip]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,259][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [x-pack-write-load-forecaster]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,264][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [search-business-rules]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,270][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [ingest-attachment]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,275][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [wildcard]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,277][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [unsigned-long]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,280][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [x-pack-sql]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,283][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [runtime-fields-common]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,288][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [x-pack-async]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,291][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [vector-tile]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,293][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2023-06-06T18:55:08,295][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [W108GXRXP3] loaded module [x-pack-eql]
[2023-06-06T18:55:20,237][WARN ][stderr                   ] [W108GXRXP3] Jun 06, 2023 6:55:20 PM org.apache.lucene.store.MemorySegmentIndexInputProvider <init>
[2023-06-06T18:55:20,295][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [W108GXRXP3] using [1] data paths, mounts [[OS (C:)]], net usable_space [258.5gb], net total_space [474.8gb], types [NTFS]
[2023-06-06T18:55:20,296][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [W108GXRXP3] heap size [15.6gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2023-06-06T18:55:20,805][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [W108GXRXP3] node name [W108GXRXP3], node ID [XLeFC-EcS0K1f9ggAwReCA], cluster name [elasticsearch], roles [data_content, transform, data_hot, ml, data_frozen, ingest, data_cold, data, remote_cluster_client, master, data_warm]
[2023-06-06T18:55:26,725][INFO ][o.e.x.m.p.l.CppLogMessageHandler] [W108GXRXP3] [controller/47000] [Main.cc@123] controller (64 bit): Version 8.8.0 (Build e011a2f1bf1ba7) Copyright (c) 2023 Elasticsearch BV
[2023-06-06T18:55:27,362][INFO ][o.e.x.s.Security         ] [W108GXRXP3] Security is enabled
[2023-06-06T18:55:28,318][INFO ][o.e.x.s.a.s.FileRolesStore] [W108GXRXP3] parsed [0] roles from file [C:\Users\Harsh_Mistry\OneDrive - Dell Technologies\Desktop\elasticsearch-8.8.0\config\roles.yml]

[2023-06-06T18:55:30,299][INFO ][o.e.x.p.ProfilingPlugin  ] [W108GXRXP3] Profiling is enabled
[2023-06-06T18:55:31,875][WARN ][stderr                   ] [W108GXRXP3] SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
[2023-06-06T18:55:31,876][WARN ][stderr                   ] [W108GXRXP3] SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
[2023-06-06T18:55:31,877][WARN ][stderr                   ] [W108GXRXP3] SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
[2023-06-06T18:55:31,878][WARN ][stderr                   ] [W108GXRXP3] SLF4J: Class path contains SLF4J bindings targeting slf4j-api versions 1.7.x or earlier.
[2023-06-06T18:55:31,879][WARN ][stderr                   ] [W108GXRXP3] SLF4J: Ignoring binding found at [jar:file:///C:/Users/Harsh_Mistry/OneDrive%20-%20Dell%20Technologies/Desktop/elasticsearch-8.8.0/modules/x-pack-security/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.19.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
[2023-06-06T18:55:31,880][WARN ][stderr                   ] [W108GXRXP3] SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#ignoredBindings for an explanation.
[2023-06-06T18:55:32,020][INFO ][o.e.t.n.NettyAllocator   ] [W108GXRXP3] creating NettyAllocator with the following configs: [name=elasticsearch_configured, chunk_size=1mb, suggested_max_allocation_size=1mb, factors={es.unsafe.use_netty_default_chunk_and_page_size=false, g1gc_enabled=true, g1gc_region_size=8mb}]
[2023-06-06T18:55:32,096][INFO ][o.e.i.r.RecoverySettings ] [W108GXRXP3] using rate limit [40mb] with [default=40mb, read=0b, write=0b, max=0b]
[2023-06-06T18:55:32,210][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [W108GXRXP3] using discovery type [multi-node] and seed hosts providers [settings]
[2023-06-06T18:55:35,472][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [W108GXRXP3] initialized
[2023-06-06T18:55:35,474][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [W108GXRXP3] starting ...
[2023-06-06T18:55:35,574][INFO ][o.e.x.s.c.f.PersistentCache] [W108GXRXP3] persistent cache index loaded
[2023-06-06T18:55:35,576][INFO ][o.e.x.d.l.DeprecationIndexingComponent] [W108GXRXP3] deprecation component started
[2023-06-06T18:55:37,132][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [W108GXRXP3] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}, {[::1]:9300}
[2023-06-06T18:55:38,706][WARN ][o.e.c.c.ClusterBootstrapService] [W108GXRXP3] this node is locked into cluster UUID [5fRKTVt2S9GC3DtMDGh5xw] but [cluster.initial_master_nodes] is set to [W108GXRXP3]; remove this setting to avoid possible data loss caused by subsequent cluster bootstrap attempts; for further information see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.8/important-settings.html#initial_master_nodes
[2023-06-06T18:55:39,068][INFO ][o.e.c.s.MasterService    ] [W108GXRXP3] elected-as-master ([1] nodes joined in term 2)[_FINISH_ELECTION_, {W108GXRXP3}{XLeFC-EcS0K1f9ggAwReCA}{TEFyiWOSRvystzJ0RKUjIg}{W108GXRXP3}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}{8.8.0} completing election], term: 2, version: 31, delta: master node changed {previous [], current [{W108GXRXP3}{XLeFC-EcS0K1f9ggAwReCA}{TEFyiWOSRvystzJ0RKUjIg}{W108GXRXP3}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}{8.8.0}]}
[2023-06-06T18:55:39,611][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService] [W108GXRXP3] master node changed {previous [], current [{W108GXRXP3}{XLeFC-EcS0K1f9ggAwReCA}{TEFyiWOSRvystzJ0RKUjIg}{W108GXRXP3}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}{8.8.0}]}, term: 2, version: 31, reason: Publication{term=2, version=31}
[2023-06-06T18:55:39,715][INFO ][o.e.c.f.AbstractFileWatchingService] [W108GXRXP3] starting file watcher ...
[2023-06-06T18:55:39,755][INFO ][o.e.c.f.AbstractFileWatchingService] [W108GXRXP3] file settings service up and running [tid=77]
[2023-06-06T18:55:39,766][INFO ][o.e.c.c.NodeJoinExecutor ] [W108GXRXP3] node-join: [{W108GXRXP3}{XLeFC-EcS0K1f9ggAwReCA}{TEFyiWOSRvystzJ0RKUjIg}{W108GXRXP3}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}{8.8.0}] with reason [completing election]
[2023-06-06T18:55:40,163][INFO ][o.e.l.ClusterStateLicenseService] [W108GXRXP3] license [1188ff3f-c6e9-4615-b8d3-02a9e966eaef] mode [basic] - valid
[2023-06-06T18:55:40,167][INFO ][o.e.x.s.a.Realms         ] [W108GXRXP3] license mode is [basic], currently licensed security realms are [reserved/reserved,file/default_file,native/default_native]
[2023-06-06T18:55:40,177][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [W108GXRXP3] recovered [1] indices into cluster_state
[2023-06-06T18:55:41,092][INFO ][o.e.h.AbstractHttpServerTransport] [W108GXRXP3] publish_address {10.91.143.74:9200}, bound_addresses {[::]:9200}
[2023-06-06T18:55:41,094][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [W108GXRXP3] started {W108GXRXP3}{XLeFC-EcS0K1f9ggAwReCA}{TEFyiWOSRvystzJ0RKUjIg}{W108GXRXP3}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}{8.8.0}{xpack.installed=true, ml.allocated_processors_double=8.0, ml.max_jvm_size=16852713472, ml.allocated_processors=8, ml.machine_memory=33706872832}
[2023-06-06T18:55:41,239][INFO ][o.e.h.n.s.HealthNodeTaskExecutor] [W108GXRXP3] Node [{W108GXRXP3}{XLeFC-EcS0K1f9ggAwReCA}] is selected as the current health node.
[2023-06-06T18:55:42,697][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [W108GXRXP3] current.health="GREEN" message="Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[.security-7][0]]])." previous.health="RED" reason="shards started [[.security-7][0]]"
```

**However, Kibana does not start at all**

I can only see the following appearing on kibana after a long time

```
[2023-06-06T18:59:40.855+05:30][INFO ][node] Kibana process configured with roles: [background_tasks, ui]
```

On start of elastic search, I see approximately 10GB of memory consumed in Java.exe

**Following is the yaml of elastic search (Trimmed the commented lines)**

```
#----------------------- BEGIN SECURITY AUTO CONFIGURATION -----------------------
#
# The following settings, TLS certificates, and keys have been automatically      
# generated to configure Elasticsearch security features on 06-06-2023 12:52:37
#
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Enable security features
xpack.security.enabled: true

xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: true

# Enable encryption for HTTP API client connections, such as Kibana, Logstash, and Agents
xpack.security.http.ssl:
  enabled: true
  keystore.path: certs/http.p12

# Enable encryption and mutual authentication between cluster nodes
xpack.security.transport.ssl:
  enabled: true
  verification_mode: certificate
  keystore.path: certs/transport.p12
  truststore.path: certs/transport.p12
# Create a new cluster with the current node only
# Additional nodes can still join the cluster later
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["W108GXRXP3"]

# Allow HTTP API connections from anywhere
# Connections are encrypted and require user authentication
http.host: 0.0.0.0

# Allow other nodes to join the cluster from anywhere
# Connections are encrypted and mutually authenticated
#transport.host: 0.0.0.0

#----------------------- END SECURITY AUTO CONFIGURATION -------------------------
```

Following is the yaml of Kibana

```
# For more configuration options see the configuration guide for Kibana in
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/index.html

# =================== System: Kibana Server ===================
# Kibana is served by a back end server. This setting specifies the port to use.
server.port: 5601

# Specifies the address to which the Kibana server will bind. IP addresses and host names are both valid values.
# The default is 'localhost', which usually means remote machines will not be able to connect.
# To allow connections from remote users, set this parameter to a non-loopback address.
server.host: "localhost"

# Enables you to specify a path to mount Kibana at if you are running behind a proxy.
# Use the `server.rewriteBasePath` setting to tell Kibana if it should remove the basePath
# from requests it receives, and to prevent a deprecation warning at startup.
# This setting cannot end in a slash.
#server.basePath: ""

# Specifies whether Kibana should rewrite requests that are prefixed with
# `server.basePath` or require that they are rewritten by your reverse proxy.
# Defaults to `false`.
#server.rewriteBasePath: false

# Specifies the public URL at which Kibana is available for end users. If
# `server.basePath` is configured this URL should end with the same basePath.
#server.publicBaseUrl: ""

# The maximum payload size in bytes for incoming server requests.
#server.maxPayload: 1048576

# The Kibana server's name. This is used for display purposes.
#server.name: "your-hostname"

# =================== System: Kibana Server (Optional) ===================
# Enables SSL and paths to the PEM-format SSL certificate and SSL key files, respectively.
# These settings enable SSL for outgoing requests from the Kibana server to the browser.
#server.ssl.enabled: false
#server.ssl.certificate: /path/to/your/server.crt
#server.ssl.key: /path/to/your/server.key

# =================== System: Elasticsearch ===================
# The URLs of the Elasticsearch instances to use for all your queries.
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]

# If your Elasticsearch is protected with basic authentication, these settings provide
# the username and password that the Kibana server uses to perform maintenance on the Kibana
# index at startup. Your Kibana users still need to authenticate with Elasticsearch, which
# is proxied through the Kibana server.
#elasticsearch.username: "kibana_system"
#elasticsearch.password: "pass"

# Kibana can also authenticate to Elasticsearch via "service account tokens".
# Service account tokens are Bearer style tokens that replace the traditional username/password based configuration.
# Use this token instead of a username/password.
# elasticsearch.serviceAccountToken: "my_token"

# Time in milliseconds to wait for Elasticsearch to respond to pings. Defaults to the value of
# the elasticsearch.requestTimeout setting.
#elasticsearch.pingTimeout: 1500

# Time in milliseconds to wait for responses from the back end or Elasticsearch. This value
# must be a positive integer.
#elasticsearch.requestTimeout: 30000

# The maximum number of sockets that can be used for communications with elasticsearch.
# Defaults to `Infinity`.
#elasticsearch.maxSockets: 1024

# Specifies whether Kibana should use compression for communications with elasticsearch
# Defaults to `false`.
#elasticsearch.compression: false

# List of Kibana client-side headers to send to Elasticsearch. To send *no* client-side
# headers, set this value to [] (an empty list).
#elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist: [ authorization ]

# Header names and values that are sent to Elasticsearch. Any custom headers cannot be overwritten
# by client-side headers, regardless of the elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist configuration.
#elasticsearch.customHeaders: {}

# Time in milliseconds for Elasticsearch to wait for responses from shards. Set to 0 to disable.
#elasticsearch.shardTimeout: 30000

# =================== System: Elasticsearch (Optional) ===================
# These files are used to verify the identity of Kibana to Elasticsearch and are required when
# xpack.security.http.ssl.client_authentication in Elasticsearch is set to required.
#elasticsearch.ssl.certificate: /path/to/your/client.crt
#elasticsearch.ssl.key: /path/to/your/client.key

# Enables you to specify a path to the PEM file for the certificate
# authority for your Elasticsearch instance.
#elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: [ "/path/to/your/CA.pem" ]

# To disregard the validity of SSL certificates, change this setting's value to 'none'.
#elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: full

# =================== System: Logging ===================
# Set the value of this setting to off to suppress all logging output, or to debug to log everything. Defaults to 'info'
#logging.root.level: debug

# Enables you to specify a file where Kibana stores log output.
#logging.appenders.default:
#  type: file
#  fileName: /var/logs/kibana.log
#  layout:
#    type: json

# Logs queries sent to Elasticsearch.
#logging.loggers:
#  - name: elasticsearch.query
#    level: debug

# Logs http responses.
#logging.loggers:
#  - name: http.server.response
#    level: debug

# Logs system usage information.
#logging.loggers:
#  - name: metrics.ops
#    level: debug

# =================== System: Other ===================
# The path where Kibana stores persistent data not saved in Elasticsearch. Defaults to data
#path.data: data

# Specifies the path where Kibana creates the process ID file.
#pid.file: /run/kibana/kibana.pid

# Set the interval in milliseconds to sample system and process performance
# metrics. Minimum is 100ms. Defaults to 5000ms.
#ops.interval: 5000

# Specifies locale to be used for all localizable strings, dates and number formats.
# Supported languages are the following: English (default) "en", Chinese "zh-CN", Japanese "ja-JP", French "fr-FR".
#i18n.locale: "en"

# =================== Frequently used (Optional)===================

# =================== Saved Objects: Migrations ===================
# Saved object migrations run at startup. If you run into migration-related issues, you might need to adjust these settings.

# The number of documents migrated at a time.
# If Kibana can't start up or upgrade due to an Elasticsearch `circuit_breaking_exception`,
# use a smaller batchSize value to reduce the memory pressure. Defaults to 1000 objects per batch.
#migrations.batchSize: 1000

# The maximum payload size for indexing batches of upgraded saved objects.
# To avoid migrations failing due to a 413 Request Entity Too Large response from Elasticsearch.
# This value should be lower than or equal to your Elasticsearch cluster’s `http.max_content_length`
# configuration option. Default: 100mb
#migrations.maxBatchSizeBytes: 100mb

# The number of times to retry temporary migration failures. Increase the setting
# if migrations fail frequently with a message such as `Unable to complete the [...] step after
# 15 attempts, terminating`. Defaults to 15
#migrations.retryAttempts: 15

# =================== Search Autocomplete ===================
# Time in milliseconds to wait for autocomplete suggestions from Elasticsearch.
# This value must be a whole number greater than zero. Defaults to 1000ms
#unifiedSearch.autocomplete.valueSuggestions.timeout: 1000

# Maximum number of documents loaded by each shard to generate autocomplete suggestions.
# This value must be a whole number greater than zero. Defaults to 100_000
#unifiedSearch.autocomplete.valueSuggestions.terminateAfter: 100000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer this on my own !

So I re-unzipped both the versions and started fresh

After that I started Elastic search with following command

```
.bin\elasticsearch.bat
```

It generates a password one time, for `elastic` user (Keep a note of it)

Also copy the Enrollment token for `Kibana` and run another prompt to fire the following command

```
.bin\kibana-setup.bat --enrollment-token --scope `<your_token>`
```

Kibana will be configured, post that it will generate few configurations automatically in `Kibana.yml` file!

**Reset the Kibana password using following command**

```
.\elasticsearch-reset-password.bat -u kibana_system --auto
```

Copy the password, update the `kibana.yml` file with this password and comment the `ServiceToken` tag !

This will start the Kibana after sometime!

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch status is GREEN and working fine. The problem is kibana yaml is not configured correctly. For example `elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]` it must be HTTPS. To configure automatically follow the steps in the [article](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.8/create-enrollment-token.html#_examples_5).

You cab run the following command to configure Kibana yaml automatically:

```
bin/elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token -s kibana
```

---

```
bin/kibana-setup --enrollment-token <enrollment-token>
```

This installation article can also help:
https://medium.com/@musabdogan/installing-elasticsearch-cluster-multi-node-cluster-with-elasticsearch-version-8-631ddc774648

Comment: WARN  org.elasticsearch.common.ssl.DiagnosticTrustManager - failed to establish trust with server at [10.91.67.16]; the server provided a certificate with subject name 
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address 10.91.67.16 found

Comment: I am getting this while creating the token

Comment: I recommend starting from the beginning. Remove es and kibana and reinstall again.

Comment: I did from starting but both of the commands are not responding till a long time

Comment: I did get Kibana configured successfully with the token command but on running , it is taking a hell lot of time